# strtok() change my buffer, I need stored some data that change in an arbitrary time, how can I do this?

Tags: python, c++, split, buffer, strtok

I have a list with coordinates sent from a Python server to a C++ client like a buffer, then I need to split each coordinate, I used strtok() for this, but when the function is tokenized for the first time do it correctly, when my while cycle repeat and received a new list of coordinates, the function returns the first token split previously, I need to saved the new coordinate list and split it in tokens like the first time, anyone knows what's my problem or a better way to solve that without use strtok()?

This is my C++ client code

```
#define _CTR_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <Winsock2.h>  
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char delimitador[] = ",";
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err, N;
    char* length;
    string D, Coordenada;

    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(1, 1);

    err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (err != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 1 ||
        HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 1) {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    SOCKET sockClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    SOCKADDR_IN addrSrv;
    addrSrv.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addrSrv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addrSrv.sin_port = htons(2070);
    connect(sockClient, (SOCKADDR*)&addrSrv, sizeof(SOCKADDR));

    const char* baseCh = { "hello" };
    char recvBuf[50], expected[50];

    send(sockClient, baseCh, strlen(baseCh), 0);

        while (1 == 1)
        {

            recv(sockClient, recvBuf, strlen(recvBuf), 0);

            strcpy(expected, recvBuf);  

            char *token = strtok(expected, delimitador);
            if (token != NULL); {
                while (token != NULL) {
                    printf("Token %s\n", token);
                    token = strtok(NULL, delimitador);
                }
            }

            send(sockClient, baseCh, strlen(baseCh), 0);

        }

    closesocket(sockClient);
    WSACleanup();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my Python Server code

```
import socket
import time

def main():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(("localhost", 2070))
    server.listen(0)
    connection, address = server.accept()
    Hand = []
    while True:

        recv_str=connection.recv(1024)[0:5]
        print("enter 1")
        recv_str=recv_str.decode("ascii")
        if not recv_str:
            break
        print( recv_str)
        
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            Hand.append(1)
            Hand.append(20)
            Hand.append(25)
            connection.send( bytes("%s," %Hand, encoding="ascii"))
            recv_str=connection.recv(1024)[0:5]
            print(Hand)
            print(recv_str)
            Hand = []
            
    connection.close()
    input("enter end")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8NKM.png)

I already put the correct code that I use and the main problem is that I need to receive a Message from a Python Server continuously at an undefined time, this message is a group of coordinates, and how you can see the function strtok() change my Buffer, I need only split the data without change the original buffer variable, like my first tokenize result but everytime that my buffer change.

Comment: The `strtok` function is documented that this is the expected behavior.   Please see the [Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) section.  Instead, write your own tokenizer instead of relying on old C functions such as `strtok`.  There are plenty of links here on StackOverflow that shows how to create such a tokenizer.

Comment: Note that there is no guarantee that `recv` receives everything that was sent in one `send`. TCP/IP is an unstructured stream of octets.

Comment: You can't assume that `socket()` succeeded. You can't assume that `connect()` succeeded. You can't assume that `recv()` succeeded. You can't assume that `recv()` didn't return -1 for end of stream. You can't assume that `recv()` filled the buffer. You can't assume that `recv()` received an entire null-terminated string. You can't assume that `send()` succeeded. Passing `strlen()` to `recv()` is meaningless. Too many basic errors here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem isn't my strtok() function, after reading an ancient question post by me, I can realize that my problem was in the recv() function my correction was

```
recv(sockClient, recvBuf, strlen(recvBuf), 0);
```

for

```
recv(sockClient, recvBuf, sizeof(recvBuf), 0);
```

This solved my problem and finally, I could receive a continuous data from Python Server to C++ client.